# results containing synonym terms not returned from Nest

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

We are attempting to get our Elastic Search Index to return us a result set which finds synonyms

```
 var synonyms = new List<string> { "egg , embryo"};
        var indexSettings = new IndexSettings();
       // <snip>
        indexSettings.Analysis.TokenFilters.Add("synonym",
                                                new SynonymTokenFilter
                                                {
                                                    Synonyms = synonyms,
                                                    Expand = false,
                                                    IgnoreCase = true,
                                                });
```

We've checked that the index that has been created contains our synonym list by looking at the  Index Metadata through Elastic Search Head.
an example synonym entry looks like;
 "egg , embryo"
however when we do a simple query we get no results with

```
return ElasticClient.Search(s => s
            .Query(q => q
                 .QueryString(qs => qs
                     .Query("egg")
                 )
             )
        );
```

Our entity looks like this (relevant properties shown)

```
[ElasticType(Name = "Entry", IdProperty = "Id")]
public class Entry
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

We have an entry indexed which has a title of "embryo". We've tried using the " => " syntax with various permutations of Expand being set to true and false.

Answer (score 1):

You've succesfully registered the new analyzer called "synonym" but you still need to apply it to the properties you'd like to set the synonym analyzer

https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/blob/master/src/Tests/Nest.Tests.Integration/Indices/Analysis/Analyzers/AnalyzerTests.cs

Has various integration tests for this.

Comment: posted follow on question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14632087/synonym-searching-in-nest